# ¿Por qué salta el error "Segmentation fault" en este código escrito en C?

Tags: c

**La idea** es la siguiente: *llamar a la función y sus argumentos mediante línea de comandos. Estos argumentos serán números y deberán imprimirse en sentido inverso al de entrada. Si se cuela algo que no sea un número, deben imprimirse los números leídos hasta ese punto*.

**El código** que he escrito es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    int max = 1000;/*Tamaño máximo de enteros aceptados*/
    int n[max]; /*Array que almacenará los enteros*/
    int count = 0; /*Contador para el número de elemetos aceptados*/

    /*Primero guardamos los números acpetados*/
    for(int i = 1; i <= argc-1 && i <= max; i++){
        if(isdigit(argv[i])){
            n[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
            count++;
        }
        else break;
    }

    /*Ahora, imprimimos en orden inverso los números aceptados*/
    for(int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%i\n", n[i]);
    }

}
```

Sé que habrá situaciones sin implementar como el caso en el que no haya argumentos de entrada en la llamada a la función (argc == 1), lo cual desembocaría en un acceso n[-1].

Sin embargo, mi intención no es profundizar en detalles sino entender cosas más generales. Supongamos entonces que siempre se hacen llamadas del estilo *funcion 1 2 3 4*.

También soy consciente de mejoras en el código, pero no me interesa hacer mejoras tampoco, sino mantener el código lo más fiel posible a su actual forma.

Siendo así, ¿por qué la línea de comandos, en lugar de imprimir los dígitos, me dice "***Segmentation fault***"?

Tengo entendido que este error está indicando un acceso indebido a memoria, pero **no sé en qué punto puedo estar accediendo a una dirección indebida de memoria**.

Gracias.

Comment: Un comentario porque no parece que sean el problema: a *isdigit* le pasas un *char** cuando deberías pasar un *int* (*char*), y *&* es *bitwise and*, no el operador lógico.

Comment: Estas compilando en C o en C++? Aunque este código compile en ambos lenguajes, son lenguajes diferentes con requisitos distintos

Comment: En C, como dice la pregunta. Añadí la etiqueta de C++ porque quienes sepan C++ también son candidatos a resolver mi problema, o eso valoré.

Comment: En cuanto al primer comentario, leí que la función isdigit() debe recibir como parámetro un char y te dice si este representa a un número. Por ejemplo, isdigit('5') sería verdadero. También leí que el operador lógico AND es representado por el símbolo &. Acabo de consultar otras fuentes y parece ser que cuando el símbolo no es doble es un AND bit a bit. Revisaré el ejercicio nuevamente con esta nueva información.

Comment: No busques candidatos, etiqueta bien la pregunta o perderás respuestas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al final, yo mismo (quien preguntó) di con la respuesta.

Primero os dejo por aquí el **código** corregido:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main (int argc, char *argv[]){

        int max = 1000;/*Tamaño máximo de enteros aceptados*/
        int n[max];/*Array que almacenará los enteros*/
        int count = 0; /*Contador para el número de elementos del array n*/

        printf("argv[1] = %p\n", argv[1]);
        printf("*argv[1] = %c\n", *argv[1]);

        /*Primero rellenamos el array de enteros*/
        /*No hay que olvidar que argv[0] contiene la llamada al programa*/
        for(int i = 1; i <= argc-1 && i <= max; i++){

                if(isdigit(*argv[i])){
                        n[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);/*El array n empieza a rellenar a partir de cero hasta max-1*/
                        count++;
                }
                else break;
        }

        /*Ahora imprimimos en orden inverso los números aceptados*/
        for(int i = count-1; i >= 0; i--){
                printf("%i\n", n[i]);
        }

}
```

El **único error** sucedía en la función **isdigit(argv[i])**, pues a dicha función le estaba pasando como parámetro la dirección de memoria del elemento y no el elemento en sí. **La sentencia correcta es isdigit(*argv[i])**.

Gracias a los compañeros que han aportado sus respuestas y comentarios, los cuales me ayudaron a solucionarlo.

Comment: Me gustaría que la revisaran antes de marcarla como definitiva, lo cual haré mañana por la noche., no vaya a ser que estuviera mal (soy nuevo en C) Muchas gracias.

Comment: Seguís teniendo esto: `n[i-1] = atoi(argv[i])`, que te va a obligar a dejar de evaluar al primer parámetro que no sea un número. Si usás `n[count]` podés sacar el `else break` y seguir evaluando (obviamente siempre que sea lo que esperás).

Comment: Otro punto es que deberías incluir los headers para `atoi` y `isdigit`. Los compiladores modernos las resuelven, pero no es una buena práctica.

Comment: La intención es obtener los dígitos hasta el primer caracter o hasta que el array n no pueda más. En cuanto a la línea que señalas, no es esa la encargada de frenar la lectura cuando encuentra un caracter, sino el condicional de isdigit()

Comment: Creo que no me expliqué bien. La línea `n[i-1] = atoi(argv[i])` funciona por existir el `else break` de  `if(isdigit(*argv[i]))`, cuando en realidad `n[count] = atoi(argv[i])` funcionaría para cualquier caso y es más legible. Además, salvo que el compilador te optimice para evitar el `i-1` cada vez, usar `n[count]` también lleva menos operaciones.

Comment: Sí, ya veo lo que propones. Es más, podría declarar  i como variable global y emplearla en lugar de count. Por haber, hay muchas maneras de hacer el problema cambiado pequeñas cosas. Y sí, creo que su método sería más eficaz, pues te ahorras una resta. Gracias por su comentario, D4RIO.

Answer (score 2):

El error se produce porque, por definición, el tamaño de los arrays debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación y ese no es tu caso:

```
int max = 1000;/*Tamaño máximo de enteros aceptados*/
int n[max]; /*Array que almacenará los enteros*/
```

En este caso `max` es una variable, así que, aunque le hayas asignado un valor inicial, a todos los efectos su valor es indeterminado para el compilador.

Dado que en este caso `max` es una constante, puedes definirla como tal:

```
#define MAX 1000
int n[MAX];
```

Con este diseño el compilador si será capaz de crear el array correctamente.

Otra opción sería usar memoria dinámica:

```
int max = 100;
int *n = (int*)malloc(max * sizeof(int));
```

El error de segmentación se está produciendo porque intentas acceder a memoria que no te pertenece. Esto se debe a que el compilador está creando un array de un tamaño inferior al que esperas y, al intentar acceder a las últimas posiciones del array, el Sistema Operativo detecta un acceso a memoria que no te pertenece. Esto último hace que el SO mate tu programa con el fin de evitar que corrompa memoria de otros procesos.

Por otro lado, en C los índices empiezan en 0 y terminan en MAX-1, luego el rango de iteración es claramente incorrecto:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= argc-1 && i <= max; i++)
```

Fíjate que estás iterando en el rango `(1, MAX)`, en vez de en el rango `(0, MAX-1)`. El bucle corregido quedaría así:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= argc-1 && i < max; i++)
```

Por otro lado tienes una incoherencia en el acceso al array `n`:

```
n[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

La variable encargada de contar el número de elementos en `n` es `count`, no `i`, luego al guardar los datos en `n` deberías utilizar `count`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= argc-1 && count < max; i++)
//                            ~~~~~~~~~~~ no más de MAX elementos en n
{
    if(isdigit(argv[i])){
        n[count] = atoi(argv[i]);
    //    ~~~~~ accedemos al elemento que toque en cada ocasión
  
        count++;
    }
    // else break;
    // ~~~~~~~~~~~ No creo que pretendas abandonar la iteración antes
    //             de tiempo
}
```

Comment: Al final he dado con la respuesta yo mismo tras mucho trastear y leer documentación. Voy a escribir la respuesta en breve. No sé si la explicaré bien, pero lo intentaré. Te recomiendo que la leas, pues está su respuesta equivocada en cuanto al razonamiento inicial. Además, es más compleja.

Comment: @SergioDuránVega El razonamiento inicial está bien, porque el compilador no sabe la dirección de memoria que tendrá la variable `max` en el futuro, por lo que no sabe su valor y no sabe cuanto debe crear el array.

Comment: @eferion ¿Los arrays los crea el compilador?. Ejemplo: `msg db 'h','o','l','a',0x0`, yó pensaba que hacia una petición al sistema operativo un rango de memoria determinado.

Comment: @DanielBriceño el compilador calcula el espacio que necesita en la pila para ello y ahí acumula el espacio del resto de variables... después generará el código que gestionará eso. Que hable o no con Sistema Operativo depende de varios factores (arquitectura del sistema, la API del SO, limitaciones hardware...), factores de los que afortunadamente no tienes que preocuparte

Comment: Gracias........

Comment: -1 por asignar un fallo de segmentación a un problema de compilación. El resto son buenos consejos, pero si la primer oración fuese cierta, entonces el programa no compilaría. La pregunta aborda un "Segmentation Fault", que es en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: @D4RIO tengo casi 50k puntos, he respondido a tantas preguntas en las que el VLA generaba errores en tiempo de ejecución que ya no puedo ni contarlas. De hecho estuve tentado de marcar, como otras tantas veces, la pregunta por duplicada

Comment: @DanielBriceño, no entiendo cómo es posible que el valor de max sea desconocido. Si yo digo que "int max = 1000;", entonces es claro. Es que este nuevo enfoque que tiene C respecto de Java (de donde vengo) es bastante lioso, la verdad.

Comment: @SergioDuránVega a ver, el compilador sí que sabe dónde se va a encontrar `max` (de hecho podrá estar en la pila del programa y/o en un registro del sistema). Si el compilador no supiese eso, el programa simplemente no funcionaría. Lo que sucede es que el compilador no puede evaluar el valor que tiene `max` en tiempo de compilación. Tiene que ser capaz de crear código que evalue el valor en tiempo de ejecución y eso es algo que no está soportado por el estándar, aparte de ser bastante problemático

Comment: Ok, ahora sí. Gracias

Comment: @eferion por favor, no argumentes "ad hominem" sobre tu misma persona usando tus puntos como validación. Indicas que "el tamaño de los arrays debe ser conocido en tiempo de compilación", y eso no es cierto precisamente porque existen los VLAs. No creo que una respuesta así sea de ayuda, por eso el -1.

Comment: @D4RIO si te informas un poco sabrás que los VLA dejaron de pertenecer al estándar con C11, es decir, hace una década ya. Si se soportan es por extensiones de los compiladores, pero no es algo ni remotamente portable y, generalmente, es propenso a dar problemas (bastantes de mis respuestas dan fe de esos problemas).

Comment: @eferion, evitá contestar mal, que no aporta. El estándar es anecdótico, acá se está compilando un VLA, sin importar el motivo. Si los VLAs estuvieran desactivados, no compilaría (probá con -Werror=vla). El error en tiempo de ejecución NO se debe a lo que se lo atribuís, por tanto no respondes la pregunta original.